# Full disk encryption using TPM2 [16.04]

Tags: 16.04, luks, tpm

I'm trying to figure out how to implement full disk encryption with auto decrypt at boot using TPM2 module.

I didn't find much information about TPM2 and xenial.

Glad if someone can pour some light on this,

Thanks