# Disk or Volume Encryption with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: server, encryption

I'm trying to encryt data partition(not a full disk encryption) with secure boot, which means I want to use TPM2 to measure some components like Grub, Linux Kernel etc. before sealing/unsealing the key used to encrypt/decrypt data partition.

Concepts might involved are: Luks2, TPM2, De-crypt, Ubuntu 20.04, Cryptsetup, Grub, Linux Kernel etc.

What steps and commands should I use to meet the requirements with security

I didn't find much information about question.

Glad if someone can pour some light on this,

Thanks

Comment: You copied and pasted someone else's [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1168560/full-disk-encryption-using-tpm2-16-04) from 2 years ago?  Ok...  Since that post didn't get any replies, you might want to consider doing it differently.  Just a suggestion...

Comment: I have edited the question and is it more clear?